# route error while i define route in view and also in route . when i define it with /

Tags: laravel, routes

In view code

```
<a href="/vendoredit/{{$vendor->id}}"><h4 class="btn btn-default" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></h4></a>

<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" href="/vendordelete/{{$vendor->id}}"><h4 class="btn btn-danger" title="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></h4></a>
```

In route.php

```
Route::get('/vendoredit/{id}','VendorslistController@edit');



Route::put('/vendordelete/{id}','VendorslistController@delete');
```

When I click on the edit or delete button, it shows the following error:

> (1/1) NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 179)
>
> at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))
>
> in Router.php (line 546)
>
> at Router->findRoute(object(Request))
>
> in Router.php (line 525)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code should be:

```
<a href="{{url('/vendoredit/'.$vendor->id)}}"><h4 class="btn btn-default" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></h4></a>

 <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" href="{{url('/vendordelete/'.$vendor->id)}}"><h4 class="btn btn-danger" title="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></h4></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to name your routes and connect links to routes using route() functions

```
Route::get('/vendor/{id}/edit','VendorslistController@edit')->name('vendor.edit');
Route::delete('/vendor/{id}','VendorslistController@delete')->('vendor.delete');
```

And in your views

```
<a href="{{route('vendor.edit',$vendor->id)}}"></a>
```

I suggest you to read Laravel's documentations about routing